# GCP AI Notebook Platform ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a GCP AI Notebook that uses PyMC3, and the notebook runs fine in GCPs jupyter lab environment (where I pip installed pymc3), but when I set the notebook to run on a scheduled job, it fails every time with a modulenotfounderror for pymc3.

Any idea what's happening here? What environment runs these notebooks for scheduled jobs and how do I install packages to them?

Comment: How did you setup the scheduled job to run your Notebook? And how did you installed the pymc3 library?